# SCSS (or CSS) layout with dynamic height header and main content below

Tags: html, css, sass

```
+-------------------+
|    Top (dynamic)  |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|    Main content   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

My **header** is an element with variable height, varying according to the content inside. This header must be fixed on the top.

When the user scrolls down, the **header** changes and decreases the size and gets a fixed height.

When i add the `position: fixed` style in the **header**, the **main** content goes up and the **header** loses the vertical space (so, the **main** content goes behind the **header**). In normal cases, I could add a **header** size margin and this space would be filled again, however, here the height is dynamic.

I need the **main** to remain in the same place as if the **header** was not with `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PLEASE USE POSITION STICKY**

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body >  p {padding: 0 20px ;}
div.sticky {
  /* Sticky bar for  */
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #6cb0f9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="sticky">This is my Sticky Header</div>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use position `sticky` instead of `fixed` on the header, as long as you don't care about IE support.

Or adjust a margin above your main to match the height of the header using JS.